# C# To use generice type delegate in class also has generic type

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I would like to make a class that accept Type as parameter, and in the meantime, I want to make a delegate which is also generic typed. The sample code is as follow. I think it should work, the OnGo delegate receives the Type as TypeAsParam from class declaration. However, the commented line is wrong. Does someone know how to fix this? Thank you all guys :)

```
public delegate void OnGo<TypeInDel>(TypeInDel obj);

public class MyClass<TypeAsParam>
{
    public OnGo<TypeAsParam> MyDelegate;
    public void Msg<TypeAsParam>()
    {
        TypeAsParam msg;
        MyDelegate(msg); //here is wrong in VS editor, says cannot cast msg to TypeAsParam(not TypeInDel)
    }
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that you meant to write `public void Msg() { /* */ }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your Msg method. In it you define new TypeParameter and so compiler cannot be sure that `TypeAsParam` from class and `TypeAsParam` from method are same. You need to remove `<TypeAsParam>` from message or to make some constraints.

Also, you need to init your msg like this:

```
var msg = default(TypeAsParam)
```

Comment: Right on, however, by using default keyword, we are assuming that the passed type will have default constructor. So it is better to put a new() constraint on it as @Ehsan-Sajjad mentioned.

Comment: @RaviMPatel i cannot agree with you. Default will always return us something, null for ref-types, in our case. I really don't like to put new() constraint, because in some cases it ruins design. Default, instead, is more tolerant

Comment: Yes, but that would mean the OnGo method will **always** get null. If that method is always going to get null, what's the point of having a parameter? Again, I'm assuming that TypeAsParam is a reference type as the name of parameter of the delegate is **obj**.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me by applying constraint on it :

```
 public delegate void OnGo<TypeInDel>(TypeInDel obj);

        public class MyClass<TypeAsParam> where TypeAsParam : new()
        {
            public OnGo<TypeAsParam> MyDelegate;

            public void Msg()
            {
                TypeAsParam msg =  new TypeAsParam();
                MyDelegate(msg); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this method is inside a class that already specifies type . That means methods of your generic class are automatically generic too.

```
public class MyClass<TypeAsParam>
      {
         public OnGo<TypeAsParam> MyDelegate;

         public void Msg(TypeAsParam msg)
         {
            MyDelegate(msg); 
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is seeing two separate declaration of your generic type, TypeAsParam, and thinks they are different things.  I have also added a default value for the msg object to avoid a secondary compiler error. Change to:

```
public delegate void OnGo<TypeInDel>(TypeInDel obj);

public class MyClass<TypeAsParam>
{
    public OnGo<TypeAsParam> MyDelegate;

    public void Msg()
    {
      TypeAsParam msg = default(TypeAsParam);
      MyDelegate(msg); //here is wrong in VS editor, says cannot cast msg to TypeAsParam(not TypeInDel)
    }
}
```